# rails server command is not working giving me 500 lines of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, windows-7-x64

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Aaron>cd sites

C:\Users\Aaron\sites>cd simple_cms

C:\Users\Aaron\sites\simple_cms>rails s
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.14/my
sql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0018 p:-9152736 s:0062 e:000061 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0017 p:---- s:0060 e:000059 CFUNC  :require
c:0016 p:0083 s:0056 e:000055 TOP    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mys
ql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0015 p:---- s:0054 e:000053 CFUNC  :require
c:0014 p:0037 s:0050 e:000049 BLOCK  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bun
dler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0047 e:000046 CFUNC  :each
c:0012 p:0055 s:0044 e:000043 BLOCK  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bun
dler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72 [FINISH]
c:0011 p:---- s:0037 e:000036 CFUNC  :each
c:0010 p:0030 s:0034 e:000033 METHOD C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bun
dler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61
c:0009 p:0013 s:0030 e:000029 METHOD C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bun
dler-1.5.1/lib/bundler.rb:131
c:0008 p:0049 s:0026 e:000025 TOP    C:/Users/Aaron/sites/simple_cms/config/appl
ication.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0024 e:000023 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0014 s:0020 e:000019 BLOCK  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0017 e:000016 CFUNC  :tap
c:0004 p:0562 s:0014 e:000013 TOP    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rai
lties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :require
c:0002 p:0034 s:0004 E:0019d8 EVAL   bin/rails:4 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0020f8 TOP    [FINISH]

bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:
in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:
in `tap'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:
in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:
in `require'
C:/Users/Aaron/sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `req
uire'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:
in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:
in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:
in `block in require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:
in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:
in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:
in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (
required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `requir
e'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa) [0x0000000076ED12FA]
C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll(WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x9c) [0x000007FEFCEC10
DC]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_vm_bugreport+0x9d) [0x000000006F286
01D]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_name_err_mesg_new+0x838) [0x0000000
06F141F98]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_bug+0x45) [0x000000006F142D45]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_check_safe_str+0x18c) [0x000000006F
20AEAC]
 [0x0000000000401A85]
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(_C_specific_handler+0x9c) [0x0000000076E985C8]
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlDecodePointer+0xad) [0x0000000076EA9D2D]
C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlUnwindEx+0xbbf) [0x0000000076E991CF]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: bin/rails

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/encdb.so
    2 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    3 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/transdb.so
    4 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/rbconfig.rb
    5 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    6 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    7 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    8 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    9 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
   10 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   11 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   12 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   13 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   14 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
   15 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   16 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   17 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system
.rb
   18 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/utf_16le.so
   19 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
   20 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   21 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
   22 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
   23 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.r
b
   24 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
   25 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/single_byte.so
   26 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   27 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   28 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/pathname.so
   29 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb
   30 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/constant
s.rb
   31 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/io/console.so
   32 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
   33 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/etc.so
   34 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
   35 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/rubygems
_integration.rb
   36 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/current_
ruby.rb
   37 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/shared_h
elpers.rb
   38 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb
   39 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/gem_path
_manipulation.rb
   40 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/gem_help
ers.rb
   41 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/match_pl
atform.rb
   42 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/rubygems
_ext.rb
   43 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/version.
rb
   44 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler.rb
   45 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/settings
.rb
   46 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/digest.so
   47 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/digest.rb
   48 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/digest/sha1.so
   49 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb
   50 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/definiti
on.rb
   51 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/dependen
cy.rb
   52 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl
.rb
   53 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
   54 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.1/lib/bundler/source.r
b
   55 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb
   56 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb
   57 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ftp.rb
   58 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb
   59 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/https.rb
   60 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldap.rb
   61 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldaps.rb
   62 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/mailto.rb
   63 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri.rb
   64 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/socket.so
   65 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb
   66 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
   67 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb
   68 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/zlib.so
   69 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/stringio.so
   70 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/exceptions.rb
   71 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/header.rb
   72 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb
   73 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/request.rb
   74 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/requests.rb
   75 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb
   76 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/responses.rb
   77 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/proxy_delta.rb
   78 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/backward.rb
   79 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb
   80 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/date_core.so
   81 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date/format.rb
   82 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date.rb
   83 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/time.rb
   84 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/request.rb
   85 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/core.rb
   86 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/util.rb
   87 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/cookie.rb
   88 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi.rb
   89 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/uri_formatter.rb
   90 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/fcntl.so
   91 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/openssl.so
   92 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/bn.rb
   93 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/cipher.rb
   94 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/config.rb
```

this is the first part of the message it gave me....

```
  374 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/mapping.rb
  375 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/alias.rb
  376 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes.rb
  377 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/streaming.rb
  378 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb
  379 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/scalar_scanner.rb
  380 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb
  381 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/emitter.rb
  382 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb
  383 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/json/ruby_events.rb
  384 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/json_tree.rb
  385 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/depth_first.rb
  386 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors.rb
  387 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/handler.rb
  388 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/tree_builder.rb
  389 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/parser.rb
  390 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/omap.rb
  391 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/set.rb
  392 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/coder.rb
  393 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/core_ext.rb
  394 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/deprecated.rb
  395 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/stream.rb
  396 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/json/yaml_events.rb
  397 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/json/tree_builder.rb
  398 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/json/stream.rb
  399 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb
  400 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb
  401 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb
  402 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb
  403 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb
  404 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb
  405 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/errors.rb
  406 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/migration.rb
  407 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/migration/join_table.rb
  408 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb
  409 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/connection_adapters/abstract/database_limits.rb
  410 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb
  411 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/descendants_tracker.rb
  412 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/callbacks.rb
  413 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb
  414 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/scoping.rb
  415 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd.rb
  416 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model
/railtie.rb
  417 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module/attr_internal.rb
  418 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module/anonymous.rb
  419 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_cont
roller.rb
  420 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb
  421 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/response.rb
  422 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispat
ch/http/filter_redirect.rb
  423 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispat
ch/http/cache.rb
  424 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispat
ch/http/response.rb
  425 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/live.rb
  426 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb
  427 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access.rb
  428 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/rescuable.rb
  429 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispat
ch/http/upload.rb
  430 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/mock_sess
ion.rb
  431 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/cook
ie_jar.rb
  432 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/mock
_digest_request.rb
  433 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/util
s.rb
  434 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/meth
ods.rb
  435 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/uplo
aded_file.rb
  436 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb
  437 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_contro
ller/metal/strong_parameters.rb
  438 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb
  439 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb
  440 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view.r
b
  441 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/v
endor/html-scanner.rb
  442 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/load_error.rb
  443 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/name_error.rb
  444 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/uri.rb
  445 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_contro
ller.rb
  446 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/r
ailtie.rb
  447 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_cont
roller/railties/routes_helpers.rb
  448 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_contro
ller/railties/helpers.rb
  449 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_contro
ller/railtie.rb
  450 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_reco
rd/railtie.rb
  451 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.2/lib/action_mail
er/version.rb
  452 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/class/delegating_attributes.rb
  453 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module/reachable.rb
  454 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb
  455 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/class.rb
  456 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.2/lib/action_mail
er.rb
  457 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.2/lib/action_mail
er/railtie.rb
  458 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit
/railtie.rb
  459 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/ver
sion.rb
  460 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike.rb
  461 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb
  462 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/string.rb
  463 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/erb.rb
  464 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/etanni.rb
  465 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/haml.rb
  466 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/css.rb
  467 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/csv.rb
  468 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/coffee.rb
  469 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/nokogiri.rb
  470 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/builder.rb
  471 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/markaby.rb
  472 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/liquid.rb
  473 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/radius.rb
  474 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/markdown.rb
  475 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/textile.rb
  476 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/rdoc.rb
  477 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/wiki.rb
  478 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/yajl.rb
  479 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/asciidoc.rb
  480 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/plain.rb
  481 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt.rb
  482 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/eco
_template.rb
  483 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/ejs
_template.rb
  484 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/jst
_processor.rb
  485 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/uti
ls.rb
  486 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/eng
ines.rb
  487 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/mime.rb
  488 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/mim
e.rb
  489 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/pro
cessor.rb
  490 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/pro
cessing.rb
  491 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/com
pressing.rb
  492 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/pat
hs.rb
  493 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/normalized_arr
ay.rb
  494 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/extensions.rb
  495 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/index.rb
  496 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/paths.rb
  497 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/trail.rb
  498 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb
  499 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/dir
ective_processor.rb
  500 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/saf
ety_colons.rb
  501 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/cha
rset_normalizer.rb
  502 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/sas
s_compressor.rb
  503 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/yui
_compressor.rb
  504 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/clo
sure_compressor.rb
  505 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/ugl
ifier_compressor.rb
  506 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/sas
s_template.rb
  507 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/scs
s_template.rb
  508 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets.rb
  509 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/benchmarkable.rb
  510 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/active_model_helper.rb
  511 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/asset_url_helper.rb
  512 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/capture_helper.rb
  513 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/tag_helper.rb
  514 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/asset_tag_helper.rb
  515 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/atom_feed_helper.rb
  516 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/cache_helper.rb
  517 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/controller_helper.rb
  518 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/csrf_helper.rb
  519 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/date_helper.rb
  520 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/debug_helper.rb
  521 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/javascript_helper.rb
  522 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/array/access.rb
  523 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/url_helper.rb
  524 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/string/filters.rb
  525 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/sanitize_helper.rb
  526 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/text_helper.rb
  527 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/form_tag_helper.rb
  528 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/tags.rb
  529 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/m
odel_naming.rb
  530 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/form_helper.rb
  531 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/form_options_helper.rb
  532 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/number_helper.rb
  533 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/number_helper.rb
  534 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/output_safety_helper.rb
  535 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb
  536 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/core_ext/module.rb
  537 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/r
ecord_identifier.rb
  538 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/record_tag_helper.rb
  539 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/rendering_helper.rb
  540 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers/translation_helper.rb
  541 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/h
elpers.rb
  542 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprocket
s/rails/helper.rb
  543 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine/co
nfiguration.rb
  544 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/applicati
on/configuration.rb
  545 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprocket
s/railtie.rb
  546 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/all.rb
  547 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_sup
port/string_inquirer.rb
  548 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/version.r
b
  549 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/error.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

C:\Users\Aaron\sites\simple_cms>
```

Just wondering if there is anything to do to fix this reinstalled everything for ruby on rails and still not working wondering if anyone has a solution...?

Comment: This is a segfault. Have you tried re-installing your Ruby?

Comment: yes i reinstalled it and everything like 3 times and still cant get the damn server to lunch so that i can test it

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have the DevKit installed (http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and its variables are loaded by running devkit\devktvars.bat .

Next, you need a MySQL library to link against. If you have MySQL loaded on your development machine, you can use that. If not, you will need to either copy the MySQL directory from your server, or else obtain a copy of the MySQL C connector: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

If you're using the connector, I recommend just getting the .zip file and unzipping it someplace convenient.

Now you can install mysql2. You must use the `--with-mysql-dir` option to tell gem where your MySQL library files are. For example, if you unzipped the connector to c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32 you would install the gem like this:

```
 gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32
```

Finally, you must copy libmysql.dll from the lib subdirectory of your MySQL or MySQL connector directory into your ruby\bin directory. In the above example, libmysql.dll would be located at c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32\lib .

Cribbed from:

https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/pull/419/files

A better suggestion:

Set yourself up on nitrous.io! It's free and you'll have a lot fewer headaches trying to develop on there than trying to find all the various hacks you'll wind up having to use developing on windows.

Comment: this didnt work i have no clue what is going on i reinstalled ruby like 3 times and still cant get the webrick to host the server idk whats going on

Comment: You're welcome to keep trying, but I'm telling you that trying to learn to develop on windows is going to be a waste of your precious time - - I spent just as much time trying various hacks just to get my environment or gems to function as I did actually learning/trying to learn anything. My advice is the same as above - - try out www.nitrous.io. It's a hosted development environment running on linux. It's free and will save you a lot of headache.